# Yes/No prompt in Python3 using strtobool

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been trying to write an elegant [y/n] prompt for scripts that I'll be running over command line. I came across this:

http://mattoc.com/python-yes-no-prompt-cli.html

This is the program I wrote up to test it (it really just involved changing raw_input to input as I'm using Python3):

```
import sys
from distutils import strtobool

def prompt(query):
    sys.stdout.write("%s [y/n]: " % query)
    val = input()
    try:
        ret = strtobool(val)
    except ValueError:
        sys.stdout.write("Please answer with y/n")
        return prompt(query)
    return ret

while True:
    if prompt("Would you like to close the program?") == True:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

However, whenever I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name strtobool
```

Changing "from distutils import strtobool" to "import distutils" doesn't help, as a NameError is raised:

```
Would you like to close the program? [y/n]: y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yes_no.py", line 15, in <module>
    if prompt("Would you like to close the program?") == True:
  File "yes_no.py", line 6, in prompt
    val = input()
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

How do I go about solving this problem?

Comment: Afaik, the piece of code I took off the website is written in 2.x, whereas I'm trying to replicate it in 3.x

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first error message:

`ImportError: cannot import name strtobool`

is telling you that there's no publically visible `strtobool` function in the `distutils` module you've imported.

This is because it's moved in python3: **use `from distutils.util import strtobool` instead.**

https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool

---

The second error message deeply confuses me -- it seems to imply that the `y` you input is trying to be interpreted as code (and therefore complains that it doesn't know about any `y` variable. I can't quite see how that'd happen!

*... two years pass ...*

Ahh, I get it now... `input` in Python 3 is "get a string from the keyboard", but `input` in Python 2 is "get a string from the keyboard, and `eval` it". Assuming you don't want to `eval` the input, use `raw_input` on Python 2 instead.

Comment: Works perfectly now! I tried to 'import distutils' and then use distutils.util.strtobool in the function too, but clearly that wasn't the right approach. The second error is still a mystery to me. Could it be because of how I'm trying to import strtobool, but the function isn't there, while the program is still trying to execute the prompt function?

Comment: Really shouldn't be; unless you've got `eval(...)` or similar somewhere in your code your data shouldn't ever get executed. (Data getting executed is often a big security problem... )

Answer (score 12):

The `distutils` package has been [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#distutils-deprecated) in Python 3.10 and will be removed from Python 3.12. Fortunately, the [`strtobool`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/distutils/util.py#L308) function is pretty small, so you can just copy its code to your module:

```
def strtobool(val):
    """Convert a string representation of truth to true (1) or false (0).
    True values are 'y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', and '1'; false values
    are 'n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', and '0'.  Raises ValueError if
    'val' is anything else.
    """
    val = val.lower()
    if val in ('y', 'yes', 't', 'true', 'on', '1'):
        return 1
    elif val in ('n', 'no', 'f', 'false', 'off', '0'):
        return 0
    else:
        raise ValueError("invalid truth value %r" % (val,))
```