# Flask_SQLAlchemy is claiming my value is not boolean?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I ran into the following error:

```
  File "/home/sandbox/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1973, in _strict_as_bool
    raise TypeError("Not a boolean value: %r" % (value,))
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) Not a boolean value: 'True'
[SQL: INSERT INTO projects (status) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: [{'status': 'True'}]]
127.0.0.1 - - [12/May/2022 21:53:22] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

I tried as boolean input everything ranging from 0|1, FALSE|TRUE, False|True on my main route. I have also tried to put in the boolean values inbetween quotations.
What am I doing wrong?

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from flask import redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

database_file = "sqlite:///DATA/DATA.db"

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = database_file
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Projects(db.Model):
    __tablename__="projects"
    status = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False, primary_key=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"projects('{self.status}')"

db.create_all()

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.form:
        status = Projects(status=request.form.get("status"))
        db.session.add(status)
        db.session.commit()
    return render_template("home.html")
```

My base route being as follows

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block body %}
<h1> Add new project </h1>
    <form method="POST" action="/">
      <select name="status" placeholder="Project Status">
        <option value=False> Not Active  </option>
        <option value=True> Active </option>
        </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Register Data">
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: 'True' is not a boolean, while True is.

Comment: I tried to alter it to db.session.add(bool(status)), though now running into sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.bool' is not mapped

Comment: With `status = Projects(status=bool(request.form.get("status")))`, you could pass 0 and 1.  `"True"` would work, but `"False"` wouldn't...

Comment: Thanks, this works. You can write it as a solution

Comment: bool("False") == True - that's not the solution you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that the form submission is returning the selection value as a string - literally `"True"` or `"False"` - while the SQL driver expects a boolean type.

There is a Python standard library function [distutils.util.strtobool](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool) which can safely convert a representation of a true or false value into a boolean type, raising a ValueError if someone puts something naughty into your API (this is much preferred to using `eval()` which [shouldn't be used on untrusted input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661084/security-of-pythons-eval-on-untrusted-strings)).

I would update your route to something like the following:

```
# At the top
from distutils.util import strtobool

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    if request.form:
        try:
            form_status = strtobool(request.form.get("status").lower())
            status = Projects(status=form_status)
            db.session.add(status)
            db.session.commit()
        except ValueError:
            # Handle the error - e.g. flash a message to the user
            flash("Invalid input")
    return render_template("home.html")
```

One thing to note with `strtobool` is that `distutils` is now deprecated as of Python 3.10, and will be removed in 3.12. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71133268/1960180) shows the implementation of it as a function, which is quite trivial, so it's worth including in your own utility functions for any code expected to last beyond Python 3.12.

Comment: Worth noting that distutils is deprecated as of Python 3.10 and will be removed in Python 3.12, so if your application is going to live longer than that it might be worthwhile implementing your own `strtobool` function

Comment: Why would they take out such useful functions :( ?

Comment: @Rivered distutils as a whole is going away, replaced with setuptools. The strtobool implementation is fairly trivial so it's probably worth including a vendored copy of the function within your own codebase. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71133268/1960180 has an example implementation

Comment: Thank you, I have included it to my helpers.py :)!